# Get a value out of a list of dictionaries from a specific key with python

Tags: python

I have a list like below, how can I get a value out of a list of dictionaries from a specific key?
I want to input `Mitsubishi` and return `2000`

```
mylist = []
a = {'car': 'Ford', 'year': 2005}
b = {'car': 'Mitsubishi', 'year': 2000}
c = {'car': 'BMW', 'year': 2019}

mylist.append(a)
mylist.append(b)
mylist.append(c)

print(mylist)
#[{'car': 'Ford', 'year': 2005}, {'car': 'Mitsubishi', 'year': 2000}, {'car': 'BMW', 'year': 2019}]
```

I have tried like that but will return all car and year values.

```
for d in mylist:
  for k, v in d.items(): 
      print(v)
```

Comment: _I have tried like that but will return all car and year values._ Isn't that to be expected?

Comment: It seems like you got the hang of most of it. I mean, you understand how to loop the list of dicts and how to then loop each dict's items. The next step is quite obvious: check if the value is `Mitsubishi` when the key is `car`. I guess you know how to use an `if` if you're familiar with loops

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Mitsubishi" is only present in one of the dictionaries:

```py
key = 'Mitsubishi'
for d in mylist:
    if d['car'] == key:
        value = d['year']
```